# Запись в базу данных

Tags: android, база-данных

Я новичек в программирвании, надеюсь на ваш совет.
Простенькое приложение для заметок.
По нажатию на fab должна происходить запись в бд 2 строк: заголовок (title) и  сама заметка (note). Но приложение падает по нажатию на fab

Метод, вносящий данные в бд:

```
fabOnCreatePage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    String title = editTitle.getText().toString();
    String note = editNote.getText().toString();
    SQLiteDatabase database = dataBase.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.fab_on_create_note:
                contentValues.put(DataBase.DB_TITLE, title);
                contentValues.put(DataBase.DB_NOTE, note);

                database.insert(DataBase.DB_NAME, null, contentValues);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

И сама бд (без onUpgrade):

```
public class DataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DB_NAME = "db";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DB_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String DB_NOTE = "note";

    public DataBase(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table notes("
                + "_id integet primary key autoincrement, "
                + DB_TITLE + "text,"
                + DB_NOTE + "text)");

    }
}
```

Сообщение об ошибке (Я его перевел, но все равно не понятно)

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.idrisov.notes/com.example.idrisov.notes.CreateNote}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:    (code 1): , while compiling: create table notes(_id integet primary key autoincrement, titletext,notetext)
```

Comment: Думаю, дело в том, что у вас пробелов нет перед `"text`, что ведёт к невалидному выражению создания БД

Comment: intege**t** -> intege**r**

Comment: @YuraIvanov благодарю. Самому стыдно за такую нелепую ошибку. Сейчас вроде работает

Comment: кстати про пробелы, они не влияют на валидность, но влияют на смысл. колонки в sqlite все строковые, указываемые типы являются affinity. данный запрос просто создаст таблицу с колонками `_id`, `titletext` и `notetext` При этом две последние колонки будут без affinity и в них можно будет записать все, что угодно впрочем как и в другие... И в зависимости от того что записано будет соответственно и интерпретировано. Иллюстрация http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/8c8ae/1 Колонка `d` как раз такая же и в ней может быть как `text` так и `integer`.

Comment: Отсюда вывод, да, ошибка в запросе есть, Юрий прав, но sqlite создаст таки таблицу, а вот работать с ней как ожидалось не получится.

Comment: @YuraIvanov, мне кажется, что если ваши комментарии в ответ оформить - хорошо и полезно получится)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, у вас синтаксическая ошибка intege**t**->intege**r**.
Во-вторых, фактическая ошибка. Не хватает пробелов между `title` и `text`, а также между `note` и `text`.

```
create table notes(_id integer primary key autoincrement, titletext,notetext)
```

Этот запрос создаст таблицу с тремя полями `_id`, `titletext` и `notetext`. При этом синтаксической ошибки не будет.

В sqlite все колонки строковые, указание типов для колонок задает лишь [affinity](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#type_affinity), т.е. правила интерпретации значений в запросах. И они вообще могут быть не указаны. Причем, если эти типы все-таки указаны при создании таблицы, все равно можно записать данные любого типа.

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/8c8ae/1) - здесь колонка `d` без указания affinity ведет себя и как строковая и как числовая в зависимости от данных, записанных в нее.

Кроме того, следует учитывать, что без указания affinity (или при хранении в колонке integer и чисел и строк одновременно) могут быть различные неожиданности при сортировке. Например, `100<'100'` и `500<'1'`, т.к. число меньше любой строки.

Таким образом, запрос без пробелов создаст таблицу, но ожидаемых колонок `title` и `note` в ней не будет, поэтому аккуратнее с конкатенациями...